# Disable validation on dynamically filled JSF OneMenu

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

first off, I'm using Primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2.2.2.

**Problem**

I'm creating a website with 200+ OneMenus (this was NOT my decision...). There is one list with options and every OneMenu is using it.

Using the "static" way causes all explorers to hang or even crash.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{day.movieEvaluatorName}" styleClass="comboboxMitarbeiter">
<f:selectItems value="#{comboListsBean.staffMembers}" var="member" itemValue="#{member.name}" itemLabel="#{member.fullName}" />
<p:ajax listener="#{...save()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now because the options list is always the same I thought "lets use some jQuery and fill the selects as soon as someone clicks on one.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{day.movieTechnicanName}" styleClass="comboboxMitarbeiter">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{day.movieTechnicanName}" itemLabel="#{day.movieTechnican}" />
<p:ajax listener="#{...save()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

JS

```
var comboboxOption = {
        <c:forEach items="#{comboListsBean.staffMembers}" var="member">
        '#{member.name}' : '#{member.fullName}',
        </c:forEach>
        };

var _select = $('<select>');
$.each(comboboxOption, function(val, text) {
    _select.append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
});

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $( ".comboboxMitarbeiter" ).focus(function() {
            $(this).append(_select.html());
        });
});
```

Now the "filling" works perfectly fine but when I try to change the value of one of the OneMenus JSF does some validation on the OneMenu, telling me the value is invalid and the "...save()" function is never called.

**Question**

How can I disable the validation on the OneMenu? I already tried with "required=false" but this didn't work. Or is there any other way to increase the performance?

Btw I posted this already in the primefaces forum but because this is a JSF question I don't think to get an answer there. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40288&e=0

Comment: You need to make sure that you have a converter and equals+hashcode implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that this is not going to work with the way JSF is designed. During the `Apply request values` phase, JSF will restore the component tree in order to update the values of each component. By this time, the *listSource* of the `SelectOneMenu` is empty. Therefore JSF cannot bind your (javascript generated) value to the component, because it's not inside the listSource which is a requirement for a SelectOneMenu.

This is not a typical validation you can disable. The contract of a `SelectOneMenu` **is** that every valid selection needs to be within its collection of elements.

If you want to populate your `SelectOneMenu`s with Javascript, you should use a jsf'ish way to achieve this. Only then the corresponding component on the backend is aware of your select-options and only then a value wihtin the `SelectOneMenu` can be valid.

Render your `SelectOneMenu`s with empty lists and a `noSelectionOption` option. Add a ajax listener that calls a method on your backing bean, whenever a user hovers the `selectOneMenu`. This method should add the desired elements to the listsource and finally `update` the `selectOneMenu` so it displays the populated values.

A simple example of this would look like this:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private List<String> options = new LinkedList<String>();
    private String selectedOption;

    public void populateList(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        this.options.add("foo");
        this.options.add("bar");
        this.options.add("baz");
    }

    public void save() {
        System.out.println(this.selectedOption);
    }

    //+getter and setter
}
```

On the ui part you just need to take care that you are not calling the listener over and over. 
The following example will load the elements, when the user hovers the select and so the ajax event becomes disabled. The `SelectOneMenu` can now be used as if it would have been filled from the beginning.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{testController.selectedOption}" id="myList">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Please select something."/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{testController.options}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item}" />
        <p:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{testController.populateList}" update="@this" disabled="#{not empty testController.options}" />        
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <p:commandButton action="#{testController.save()}"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This showed me the right direction. I'm now "clicking" a hidden button as soon as $(document).ready to populate the list on the server and use the js-append methode from my question on client side.